# paste image in Whatsapp chat using js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, paste

I want to paste image from my clipboard to whatsapp chat from clipboard i tried using document exec command with different parameters like insertHTML , insertImage these two add image in content editable div but does not enable the send button. I also tried using document exec command paste but its pasting nothing. I double checked and images exists on clipboard.

```
async function sendToChat(blob) {
    setToClipboardImg(blob)
    try {
        document.querySelector('._6h3Ps ._13NKt').focus()
    } catch (e) {
        document.querySelector('textarea').focus()
    }
    // const data = [new ClipboardItem({
    //     [text.type]: text
    // })]
    // await navigator.clipboard.write(data)
    document.execCommand("Paste", null, null);
    //setToClipboardWithTextInsta()
}

var setToClipboardImg = async blob => {
    window.focus();
    const data = [new ClipboardItem({
        [blob.type]: blob
    })]
    await navigator.clipboard.write(data);
  
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed exactly the same funcionality, I was able to resolve it using html2canvas, you can convert an html element into an image and then send it through whatsapp from the clipboard, here is how I implemented it:

```
document.querySelector("#btn").onclick(function () {

var table =  document.querySelector("#table");
var elementContainer =  document.querySelector("#previewImage");

 try {
   // Prevent duplicates since the element will be appended to the container

if (elementContainer.innerHTML) {
    elementContainer.innerHTML = "";
 }
       
       
 html2canvas(table).then(canvas => {
 elementContainer.appendChild(canvas);
 canvas.toBlob(blob => navigator.clipboard.write([new 
 ClipboardItem({'image/png': blob})]));
    
    alert(' The screenshot for the table currently displayed was copied to the clipboard, you can now paste into the WhatsApp chats ');
});

        }


catch(err){
document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = err.message;
   }
}
```

Then in the head of the document add the following cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```